# Adding new events to iCal with PUT request from PHP client?

Tags: request, icalendar, put, caldav

I'm trying to synchronize PHP-written calendar with Kerio Connect calendar(iCal).
I have no problems with connecting to calendar and  fetching events.
But when I try to PUT any new event it seems that empty event is added, for example:

my request:

HEADERS:
PUT /calendars/localhost/marcin/Calendar HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic bWFyY2luOnJob21hbg==
Host: localhost:1212
If-None-Match: *
Content-type: text/icalendar Content-Length: 367

REQEST:
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Kerio Technologies//Kerio Connect//EN
METHOD:PUBLISH
VERSION:2.0
X-VERSION-KMS:6.2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20120528T163000
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20120528T170000
SEQUENCE:0 SUMMARY:test event
CLASS:PUBLIC PRIORITY:5
TRANSP:OPAQUE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
X-LABEL:0
END:VEVENT
 END:VCALENDAR

RESPONSE:
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Allow: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, DELETE, PUT, COPY, MOVE, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, SEARCH, SUBSCRIBE, UNSUBSCRIBE, POLL, BDELETE, BCOPY, BMOVE, BPROPPATCH, BPROPFIND, LOCK, UNLOCK
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Sun, 27 May 2012 13:33:04 GMT
ETag: 1f353abd967f4700b8dc18f4d4775ff30000003400000001
Location: /calendars/localhost/marcin/Calendar/
Repl-UID: ResourceTag:

doesn't matter what dates/subject I put in request, created event always looks like this:
Subject:
Date: Sun, 27 May 2012 15:33:04 +0200
Content-Type: text/calendar; component="vevent"; method="PUBLISH"; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Kerio Technologies//Kerio Connect//EN
METHOD:PUBLISH
VERSION:2.0
X-VERSION-KMS:6.2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20120527T133304Z
UID:10a69ad8-07f1-4831-a015-4de3dac78351
TRANSP:OPAQUE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

So there is no subject, and no dates (DTSTART,DTEND);
I've tried to send empty request:
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VEVENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

and the result was the same.

I'm new to calDAV and I'm trying to solve this for last few days.
If someone could help me and tell me what am I doing wrong, it would be awesome.

Best Regards
Martin

Answer (score 1):

I too am had the exact issue.  I push the event but kerio shows no subject or dates. Here is what I found to work (I could only get curl to work, no luck with fsockopen):

```
$uid = "test-12345"; // setting this to an existing uid updates event, a new uid adds event
$url = $account['uri'].'/'.$uid.'.ics'; //http://mail.domain.com/calendars/DOMAIN/USER/Calendar/'.$uid.'.ics'
$userpwd = $account['user'] .":". $account['pass'];
$description = 'My event description here';
$summary = 'My event title 1';
$tstart = '201206015T000000Z';
$tend = '20120616T000000Z';
$tstamp = gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z");

$body = <<<__EOD
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:$tstamp
DTSTART:$tstart
DTEND:$tend
UID:$uid
DESCRIPTION:$description
LOCATION:Office
SUMMARY:$summary
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
__EOD;

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8',
    'If-None-Match: *',
    'Expect: ',
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($body),
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userpwd);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I was able to finally get fsockopen to work instead of curl.  The problem was content-type header sent.  It does not like text/icalendar.  Try using text/calendar instead, that worked for me.

Comment: Hi, could you help me a bit for my case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50720196/creating-new-event-to-icloud-apple-calendar-always-results-400-bad-request