# Creating New Event to iCloud Apple Calendar always Results 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, icloud, webdav, caldav

Currently, I am developing a website which will sync data from Apple Calendar to my app and vice versa.

For fetching data from Apple Calendar to my application, I already can get the `.ics` files from iCloud calendar and it works just fine.

However, I have an issue when creating new Event in Apple Calendar. Somehow, every request that I send results `400 Bad Request`.

Here is the detail of the request:

1. Header: `If-None-Match: *`
2. Method: `PUT`
3. Uri destination: `https://p46-caldav.icloud.com/[USER_ID]/calendars/work/dfsfsdfsfsfsfsdfsdfsdf.ics`
4. Content type: `text/calendar`
5. Apple Id and App Specific Password are set using [NetworkCredential](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential(v=vs.110).aspx). This works fine for fetching data from Apple Calendar, so I don't think this is the source of the problem. Here is the snipped code of it: `httpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);`
6. For request content, actually I have tried so many things. Here I will just set the one from [RFC 4791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791#section-5.3.2)

`BEGIN:VCALENDAR VERSION:2.0 PRODID:-//Example Corp.//CalDAV Client//EN BEGIN:VEVENT UID:20010712T182145Z-123401@example.com DTSTAMP:20060712T182145Z DTSTART:20060714T170000Z DTEND:20060715T040000Z SUMMARY:Bastille Day Party END:VEVENT END:VCALENDAR`

Anyone knows what possibly can be wrong?

Comment: There is no HTTP body in the 400 response ?

Comment: I just checked it and it has this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><error xmlns="DAV:"><Require-User-Agent xmlns="http://cal.me.com/_namespace/" /><error-description xmlns="urn:mobileme:davservices">User-Agent Header is required</error-description></error>`

Comment: Thanks @ArnaudQuillaud , you gave me clue for fixing it. Now it works fine. Once, I set the `User Agent` properties, it works like a charm.

Comment: @YusrilMaulidanRaji Would you mind sharing how you got the CalDav to work? I am trying to see if I can get CardDav to work and maybe this is what I am looking for. I was unable to figure out how to get either of them working. [SO Question link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51738343/apple-icloud-access-to-contacts-in-uwp-application)

Comment: Hey i also want to create edit events into apple calendar using .net core can you please reference on code

Answer (score 0):

Here's working C# code illustrating how to add a new event via WebDAV and iCal to Apple iCalendar calendar. The used NuGet packages are:

- **Ical.Net 4.2.0 by Rian Stockbower, Douglas Day, & Contributors** - implements a .NET interface for ical; the code below uses it to compose and serialize a new calendar event, preparing it for WebDAV.
- **WebDav.Clien 2.8.0 by skazantsev** - implements a .NET interface for WebDAV; the code below uses it to authenticate with `caldav.icloud.com` and put the new event on the Apple server.

Further important details can be extracted from the code and the code comments.

```cs
using System.Net;
using Ical.Net.CalendarComponents;
using Ical.Net.DataTypes;
using Ical.Net.Serialization;
using Ical.Net;
using WebDav;

namespace Falael.Auto.Mon.Acq
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //  webdav client
            var webDavClientParams = new WebDavClientParams
            {
                //  pXXX can be acquired from the public URL when the calendar is marked 
                //      as Public Calendar from the icloud.com web calendar
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https://pXXX-caldav.icloud.com"),
                //  an apple-app-specific-password can be acquired via icloud.com,
                //      "Manage Apple ID", App-Specific Passwords
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("apple-id", "apple-app-specific-password")
            };

            //  can be acquired from network activity in chrome dev tools in icloud.com web 
            //      calendar by inspecting the first POST request when creating a new event
            var dsid = "1234567890";

            var client = new WebDavClient(webDavClientParams);
            try
            {
                var response = await client.Propfind($"/{dsid}/calendars");
                foreach (var res in response.Resources)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Resource URI: {res.Uri}, {res.Properties.Count}");
                    var response2 = await client.Propfind(res.Uri);
                    foreach (var resource in response2.Resources)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"-- Resource URI: {resource.Uri}, {resource.Properties.Count}");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }

            //  can be acquired by identifying the correct id from the calendar ids listed by the 
            //      above code; i used the number of events in each calendar to diversify
            var calendarId = "04690ac0-9911-4466-b30e-4c9d0f38dcde";

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //  ical
            var calendar = new Ical.Net.Calendar();
            var now = DateTime.Now;

            var calendarEvent = new CalendarEvent
            {
                Start = new CalDateTime(now.AddMinutes(5)),
                End = new CalDateTime(now.AddMinutes(5).AddHours(1)),
                Summary = "Test Event",
                Description = "This is a test event"            
            };
            calendarEvent.Alarms.Add(new Alarm 
            {
                Trigger = new Trigger(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(-1)),
                Action = AlarmAction.Display
            });
            calendarEvent.Alarms.Add(new Alarm
            {
                Trigger = new Trigger(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(-1)),
                Action = AlarmAction.Audio
            });

            calendar.Events.Add(calendarEvent);

            var serializer = new CalendarSerializer(new SerializationContext());
            var serializedCalendar = serializer.SerializeToString(calendar);
            var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedCalendar);
            var httpContent = new System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent(bytes);

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //  create new event
            var eventUri = $"/{dsid}/calendars/{calendarId}/" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".ics";
            var putFileParameters = new PutFileParameters
            {
                ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/calendar"),
                Headers = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
                {
                    { "If-None-Match", "*" }, 
                    { "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; GoogleCalendarClient/1.0)" } 
                }
            };
            var content = new StringContent(serializedCalendar, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/calendar");
            var result = await client.PutFile(eventUri, content, putFileParameters);

            //  on success will show 201
            Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

See Also: https://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/#discovery - Contains valuable information on how to use WebDAV (all examples are pure XML), which could be applied also in the case of WebDAV with ical. Requires some preliminary knowledge on WebDAV, though.